# Windows Server 2008 R2 - allow more time to reset password

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy, password, password-reset

Good morning everyone!

I apologize if this has been asked - I have tried searching every where I can think of, to include the search bar here on serverfault.

I work as an IT technician at a high school, and during our first week of school, we have freshman resetting their passwords. Due to the complexity rules, it seems to be difficult for some of the freshman to think of a password that meets the default complexity. By the time they have tried two passwords, the connection seems to refresh, and they are taken back to the original screen, having to press Ctrl + Alt + Delete, re-enter their username and default password, then try again. We are using NComputing L300 devices to remotely connect to the server. Any ideas on how to increase this refresh rate so they have more time to try passwords? Would this be a server issue, monitor issue, or the NComputing L300 issue?? I have tried looking into all three of these, and haven't been able to find anything that could be of help.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: No, I don't think there is.